# How to repaint figures in java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

I tried to paint some figures as you can see below ( I did not include the other class which involve main method)... the problem that it does not repaint I just get three thick lines as output but it should draw an oval and two rectangles so they move in the frame as the while loop works ...

```
package shapes;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    int n1=0;
    int n2=0;
    int n3=0;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        do {
        // super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(n1++, 33, 54, 84);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(100, n2++, 56, 97);
//      g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawOval(44, n3++, 44, 66);


        } while (n1<=500 && n2<=500 && n3<=500);
        n1++;
        n2++;
        n3++;
        repaint();
      }
    }
```

how to correct the code to make it repaints the figures for each loop so it does not show three thick lines as output ??? (I want the do command is included) ..
thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Never invoke repaint() in a painting method - this will cause an infinite loop. `so it does not show three thick lines` - well that is what you are telling the code to do. First you paint a rectangle starting at (0, 33), then (1, 33), then (2, 33), so of course you are going to get a big thick line that is 554 pixels wide (500 + 54) and 84 pixels high. I have no idea why you have 3 variables that all have the same value. Are you trying to do some kind of animation where the painting changes 500 times?

Comment: Note: paintComponent have to paint object current state.
You should update the state somewhere else, usually in dedicated thread. Every time you update the state, make call to `repaint()` or  `repaint(50)` where 50 is repaint delay n miliseconds

Answer (score 1):

1. Call `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting (and not within your loop);
2. Don't call `repaint` from within paint methods, this could setup an infinite loop of repaints which could consume all your CPU cycles;
3. Use a Swing `Timer` instead to generate scheduled updates and animation